# When looping the selection_history of a bemesh it Crashes With Error: HIPEW initialization failed: Error opening HIP dynamic library

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I'm Making a tool for boundary weight paint pinning from selection with bmesh 
Am i supposed to report this as a Bug ?

**Edit:**
the script works with no issues when using selection_history.active instead of looping through selection_history

if 2 or more faces are selected at the same time in edit mode and the script below is run it will instantly crash blender with this as the debug_log

**Error:**

```
***** *************** ***** device.cpp:34] CUEW initialization succeeded
***** *************** ***** device.cpp:36] Found precompiled kernels
***** *************** ***** device.cpp:61] HIPEW initialization failed: Error opening HIP dynamic library
```

Recreate the linked image in a new blend file to prove it's not file dependent

**To recreate:**

1. 2 strips that are 3 or more faces long of connected 4 sided faces under the same mesh object
2. select as illustrated in the image
3. run script

**Script:**

```
import bpy
import bmesh

if (bpy.context.mode == "EDIT_MESH") and (bpy.context.edit_object.type == "MESH"):
    bpy.context.BMesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.edit_object.data)
    PinGroup = None
    for VxGroup in bpy.context.edit_object.vertex_groups:
        if (PinGroup is None) and (VxGroup.name.lower() == "pin"):
            PinGroup = VxGroup
    else:
        if (PinGroup is None):
            PinGroup = bpy.context.edit_object.vertex_groups.new(name="Pin")
    if (PinGroup is not None):
        PinGroup.name = "Pin"
        for SelectionItem in bpy.contextBMesh.select_history:
            if (SelectionItem is not None) and (SelectionItem.__class__ is bmesh.types.BMFace):
                BoundaryVertex = []
                NonBoundaryEdge = []
                DividingNonBoundaryEdge = []
                for Edge in SelectionItem.edges :
                    if (Edge.is_boundary == True):
                        BoundaryVertex.extend([Vertex for Vertex in Edge.verts if (Vertex not in BoundaryVertex)])
                    
                for Vertex in BoundaryVertex:
                    for Edge in Vertex.link_edges:
                        if (Edge.is_boundary == False):
                            if (Edge not in NonBoundaryEdge):
                                NonBoundaryEdge.append(Edge)
                            if (Edge in NonBoundaryEdge):
                                DividingNonBoundaryEdge.append(Edge)

                AddVertex = [Vertex.index for Vertex in BoundaryVertex]
                RemoveVertex = [Vertex.index for Edge in DividingNonBoundaryEdge for Vertex in Edge.verts]

                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
                PinGroup.add(index=AddVertex, weight=1.0, type="REPLACE")
                PinGroup.remove(index=RemoveVertex)
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
```

[image: Make this in a fresh file]

Comment: You're modifying the selection history while iterating over it. I suggest doing operations after you've initialized your arrays. BTW I'm pretty sure going out and then back in edit mode invalidates the `bm` so I'm not surprised it crashes when you try to access it in the next loop cycle :)

Comment: also this `for SelectionItem in bpy.contextBMesh.select_history` should throw an error unless I'm mistaken ?

Comment: the selection is not being modified, i am aware of the invalidation but the mode change happens only after the bm is not used anymore, as the data relevant to the mode change is stored as list of indexes, also there is a copy-paste error as the second history access is supposed to be SelectionItem, just noticed that

Comment: the main issues with this is it doesn't simply throw an error, i have no idea what even that library that is failing is, when the bmesh is discarded is taken into account and i avoided editing selection_history because it was giving console errors, but when i loop through it, it won't tell me anything else other than that bit of debug_log

Comment: Then I think you have an indentation problem, the last 4 lines are run within the `for SelectionItem in bpy.contextBMesh.select_history:` loop. Also fwiw a suggestion `(SelectionItem.__class__ is bmesh.types.BMFace)` => `isinstance(SelectionItem, bmesh.types.BMFace)` more readable imo

Comment: note you can get a debug log if your blender crashes if you launch `blender_debug_log.cmd` from your blender installation. I re-read my comment nad you're right that you don't modify the selection history, but you're still accessing an invalid object after you went out of edit mode

Comment: can you make it an answer please, i just realized what was wrong with it other that the last 4 lines, i was also passing vertecies that didn't exist anymore in the last 2  comprenshion lists making the operator throw a lot of errors, making this at 2 in the morning was the cause all along